# -bash: nodemon: command not found

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Olá, gostaria de saber se tem alguém com o mesmo problema ou algum similar
Eu executei esse código `sudo npm install nodemon` e me retornou isso

```
/Users/apple/.npm-global/bin/nodemon -> /Users/apple/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js

nodemon@2.0.2 postinstall /Users/apple/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon
node bin/postinstall || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective
https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

nodemon@2.0.2
```

Aparentemente, o `nodemon` foi instalado normalmente, mas quando eu executo o `nodemon` ele aparece `-bash: nodemon: command not found`

Eu não sei o que fazer, já tentei colocar o nodemon no diretório de node_modules, já tentei colocar `-g (globalmente)`, mas nada funciona

Eu estou num MacBook Air 10.15.2 macOS Catalina

Comment: Se escreveres `node /Users/apple/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon` ele corre?

Comment: O `nodemon` só funciona com `--save-dev`, está no README da página e do npmjs.org deles e se for pra instalar global será usando sudo e com `sudo npm i -g nodemon`... ainda se for global e fez tudo certo e não funciona então é provavel que nenhum pacote de CLI irá funcionar e que você está com problema no seu `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu fiz um teste utilizando o High Sierra e funcionou, vou descrever o que eu fiz

Eu criei uma pasta, e dentro dela, pelo terminal, digitei:

```
npm init
```

Para criar o package.json. Depois, eu instalei o nodemon neste projeto da seguinte forma:

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

Criei um arquivo index.js com uma programação de testes. Editei o arquivo package.json e fiz o seguinte acréscimo na parte de "scripts"

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
}
```

Depois de salvar a alteração, pelo terminal, executei a aplicação Node da seguinte forma:

```
npm start
```

O nodemon foi executado junto com o script de testes.

Comment: Bem, não consegui achar a solução que eu queria pro meu problema, mas achei uma forma de burlar, eu coloquei dentro do `package.json` a variavel `serve` que execulta `nodemon server.js` e funcionou e é só colocar `npm run serve` que começa a rodar o nodemon, mas pelo visto `start`é uma variavel muito melhor á se colocar, muito obrigado

Answer (score 2):

No linux você precisa adicionar npx antes do nodemon

```
npx nodemon app.js
```

Já no windows você não precisa fazer isso basta utilizar

```
nodemon app.js
```

Claro so não esquece de instalar o nodemon no projeto, não recomendo instalação global.

**NPM**

```
npm install nodemon --save-dev
```

**Yarn**

```
yarn add nodemon -D
```